# How to restrict PlaceAutocompleteFragment to only show public transport stations? Android

Tags: android, google-maps, transport, placeautocompletefragment

I am in process of making a public transport app and for that cause I want to restrict my `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` to only Tram, Bus and Train Stations within my city.

So far I have implemented g`oogle map`, place autocomplete fragment and restricted it to my country and city. This is part of my code:

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(45.707197, 15.665182),
            new LatLng(45.913958, 16.277670)));

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setCountry("HR")
            .build();

    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

I looked into filters and I couldn't find anything like public transport stations. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutocompleteFilter` only provides a few [types](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter), as you already probably know. I think you have two options:

1) Use `Place Autocomplete Web Service`, I believe you will be able to filter the returned result in the URL, you will have to try.
2) Google provides tables for the place types [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). The establishment type that you need is available in `Table 1`, which corresponds to [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), which is also a web service.

So for both, you will have to make an HTTP request. But unfortunately, you cannot filter them using `AutocompleteFilter`. But for the sake of trying:

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_BANK)
                .build();
```

And it doesn't work either. So your possible option is to use the Web Service.